# Adding screenshot in extent report 4 for the failed scenarios

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I'm using extent report 4.Actually I'm trying to add Screenshot in extent report when the test fails. I'm using below code to achieve this. Screenshot gets attached in the end of my report (please refer the screenshot), but I want screenshot to get attached in the appropriate step i.e. when the test cases fail. Please help me with solutions or workaround

```
            case FAIL:
            String path = WrapperMethods.captureScreenshot();
            try 
            {
                test.log(logStatus, message + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(path));
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
```

[image]

Comment: Add screen shot code to those catch block of action methods where ever u want to capture.

Comment: I'm not getting your answer @TheSociety

Answer (score 0):

for version 4  you can work as below

```
if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            test.fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + "Test Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
            test.fail(result.getThrowable());
            String screencastPath = null;
            try {
                screencastPath = Screeshot.captureScreenshot(WebDriverManager.driver);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                test.fail("<b><font color=blue>" + "Screenshot Name: " + Screeshot.sendScreenName() + "</font></b>");
                test.fail("<b><font color=red>"
                        + " Click the below link OR check the report folder by above screenshot Name to get the Screenshot of failure "
                        + "</font></b>", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(screencastPath).build());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                test.fail("Test Failed, Cannot attach screeshot");
            }
            WebDriverManager.driver.close();
        }
```